# how is possible deleting complex items in a dynamic list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to implement a delete feature for a list of elements but the onDelete event doesn't work as expected.

Here's the code:

```
    
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager = DataManager.shared
    @State var isAddShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List($dm.TTDItemList) { $item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        TextEditor(text: $item.itemDesc)
                            .onTapGesture {}
                        Text(item.ItemTagsToText())
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                    
                }
                .onDelete(perform: cancella)
            }
            .onTapGesture { hideKeyboardAndSave() }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Board"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    Button(action: { withAnimation { self.isAddShown.toggle() } }) {
                Image(systemName: !isAddShown ? "plus.circle.fill" : "minus.circle.fill").imageScale(.large)
            }
            )
        }
    }
    
    private func hideKeyboardAndSave() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        dm.salva()
    }
    
    func cancella(at offset: IndexSet) {
        guard let intindex = Array(offset).first else { return }
        dm.TTDItemList.remove(at: intindex)
        dm.salva()
    }
    
    
}
```

The error I receive is:

> Value of type 'List<Never, ForEach<LazyMapSequence<Array.Indices, (Array.Index, UUID)>, UUID, VStack<TupleView<(some View, some View)>>>>' (aka 'List<Never, ForEach<LazyMapSequence<Range, (Int, UUID)>, UUID, VStack<TupleView<(some View, some View)>>>>') has no member 'onDelete'

Implementing the List was tricky, but the code seems working allowing saving the modifications in the data manager.

Comment: `onDelete` is used in a `ForEach` not a `List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `onDelete` modifier is a method of `ForEach`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/ForEach/onDelete(perform:)). It is not defined for other `View`s like `List`. You need to modify your code to use a `ForEach` inside your `List`.

```
            List {
                ForEach($dm.TTDItemList) { $item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        TextEditor(text: $item.itemDesc)
                            .onTapGesture {}
                        Text(item.ItemTagsToText())
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                    
                }
                .onDelete(perform: cancella)
            }
```

---

Technically, `onDelete` is an extension method of the `DynamicViewContent` protocol, but the only types that conform to `DynamicViewContent` are `ForEach` and modified derivatives of `ForEach`.